# Group collection by date in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to group my results by date.  My date field is a mySQL timestamp and I am using Laravel 4.1.  For the purpose of this, I am using a field named 'start_time' and need it to group literally by date only, disregarding the actual time.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I am unfamiliar with using dates like this in this framework.

```
$agenda = Agenda::where('active', '=', 'Y');
$agenda->with('user');
$agenda->with('room');
$agenda->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(start_time, "%d/%m/%Y")'));
$agenda->orderBy('start_time', 'asc');
$agenda->distinct();
$agenda->get();

return View::make('agenda')->with('agendas', $agenda);

@foreach($agendas as $agenda)
  {{ date("d M Y",strtotime($agenda->start_time)) }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a very basic approach but that's how I always do it:

```
<?php $currentDate = null ?>
@foreach($agendas as $agenda)
    <?php $date = date("d M Y",strtotime($agenda->start_time)); ?>
    @if($currentDate != $date)
        <?php $currentDate = $date; ?>
        <h3>{{ $date }}</h3>
    @endif

    {{-- do the stuff --}}
@endforeach
```

It would be nice (and best/better practice) not to do the date formatting like this in the view. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

May be you would split to more foreach loop (?) .
At first, we will query to get all of `start_time` with distinct, order, eta...
Then, push a foreach loop to get data belonged to each `start_time` element.
Hope this will be usefull.